# Not getting int value in long type divison but getting casting error in Groovy

Tags: groovy

```
Long sizeLongVar = 3308651187 
intValue = (int)(sizeLongVar/1073741824)
log intValue
```

getting below error while printing `intValue`

```
Cannot cast object '3.08' with class 'com.tdsops.etl.Element' to class 'int' at line 135
```

Comment: What is the version of Groovy?

Comment: Can you show us the imports? Where is tsdops coming from?

Comment: Looks like you have operator overloading for div method.

Comment: Groovy version 2.4

Comment: tsdops is application name